# What is this LEGO part (kind of wheel or gear) number?

Tags: part-identification

I recently found a really nice MOC of the AT-TE from which I try to get inspiration. But there is one part that I really cannot identify... I wonder if anyone can tell me its part number. Here is a picture:

[image: The part that I'm looking for]

It seems to me to be a kind of Technic wheel or gear, but I couldn't find it on Bricklink...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a bit tricky to find this piece on Bricklink. Even though I knew the part it took me a little to find it.

The part you are interested in is [Hero Factory Weapon Barrel with 2 Pin Holes and 3 Axle Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98585#T=C). Default item part number is 98585, but 31511, 31520 could also be used for other colors by LEGO.

[image]